# JSON irregular data to R dataframe

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I thought the question is simple but it got me. Say I have a json file be like:

> {"key1":["value1"],
>   "key2":["value2", "value3", "value4"],
>   "key3":["value5", "value6"]}

I want to import them to a data frame like:

```
0 key value
1 key1 value1
2 key2 value2
3 key2 value3
4 key2 value4
5 key3 value5
6 key3 value6
```

Tried jsonlite and rjson fromJSON function with different arguments, it returns a few lists instead of dataframe

Tried several answers from other questions but still cannot figure it out. Help is appreicated!

Was trying unlist function and got an ugly approach (with inspiration from [R unlist changes names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163648/r-unlist-changes-names)):

```
json <- '{"key1":["value1"],
  "key2":["value2", "value3", "value4"],
  "key3":["value5", "value6"]}'

jsonR <- fromJSON(txt = json)

data.frame(key = rep(names(jsonR ), lengths(jsonR )), value = unlist(jsonR , use.names=F))
```

Comment: The JSON as you posted it is not valid JSON.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen would you explain the invalid part?

Comment: Strings need to be quoted in JSON. Object keys are strings.

Comment: is it correct now?

Comment: No. Needs to be double quotes.

Comment: used jsonlite  ? fromJSON(txt, simplifyVector = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = simplifyVector,
  simplifyMatrix = simplifyVector, flatten = FALSE, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the [`stack`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/stack.html) and the [`rev`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rev.html) functions (respectively from `utils` and `base` packages) to achieve this :

```
> json <- '{"key1":["value1"],
+   "key2":["value2", "value3", "value4"],
+   "key3":["value5", "value6"]}'
> 
> df <- rev(stack(fromJSON(txt=json)))
> colnames(df) <- c('key', 'value')
> df
   key  value
1 key1 value1
2 key2 value2
3 key2 value3
4 key2 value4
5 key3 value5
6 key3 value6
```

Comment: beautiful! Thanks mgc