# Unpack a list by duplicating elements longer than 1

Tags: r

I have the following list that I wish to *unpack* (aka expand) using **only** base `R`.

For example, I want to turn this:

`b <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = 1, d = c(5, 7))`

into the equivalent of:

`list(a = 1, a = 2, b = 1, d = 5, d = 7)`

I have this function that works if only one named element has length > 1 but not if there are multiple elements:

```
expand_list <- function(listx){
  long_elements <- as.numeric(which(lapply(listx, length) > 1))
  short_elements <- as.numeric(which(lapply(listx, length) == 1))

  res <- lapply(long_elements, function(x){
    as.list(setNames(listx[[x]], rep(names(listx)[x], length(listx[[x]]))))
  }) 

  expanded_elements <- res[[1]]
  c(listx[short_elements], expanded_elements)
}

expand_list(b)
```

Comment: Related discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163648/r-unlist-changes-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stack` followed by `setNames` to achieve that

```
y <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = 1, c = 2, d = c(5, 7))
x <- stack(y)
as.list(setNames(x$values, x$ind))
```